# How to use MLlib model in streaming queries (fails with "Field "features" does not exist.")?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to use a saved Mllib model to predict sentiment on live streaming data.

I've tried all the recommendations I have found but still I get errors.
Current error :Field "features" does not exist.

The schema of trained data is

```
root
 |-- label: double (nullable = true)
 |-- words: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```

```
lines = spark\
        .readStream\
        .format("kafka")\
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)\
        .option("subscribe", topics)\
        .load()\
        .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
    #<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>

read_data=lines.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as text")

model_nb = NaiveBayesModel.load("./myNBmodel")

prediction = model_nb.transform(read_data)

print(prediction.schema)

query1 = prediction.writeStream \
            .outputMode("update") \
            .foreach(process_row) \
            .start()

query1.awaitTermination()
```

```
prediction = model_nb.transform(read_data)
```

> :Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o133.transform.
>   : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "features" does not exist.
>   Available fields: text

Fetced data don't need features in order to have a prediction, right?

Answer (score 0):

> Fetced data don't need features in order to have a prediction, right?

That's rather incorrect.

Raw data has to be "featured" and that's why you should be using Spark MLlib's [ML Pipelines](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html) so it's Spark to do this "featurization" not you:

> **ML Pipelines** provide a uniform set of high-level APIs built on top of DataFrames that help users create and tune practical machine learning pipelines.
>
> MLlib standardizes APIs for machine learning algorithms to make it easier to combine multiple algorithms into a single pipeline, or workflow.